# C# Web Application Form using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, webforms

As a DBA/SQL Server Developer, I'm often asked to produce web pages where users can view the data in the database and edit them, and see the edits they've made straight away (without refreshing the page). I know nothing about ADO.NET or C#, but I would like to be able to give users this very simple functionality. Essentially I'm looking for three things:

- to display a table of data in a webpage retrieved from a SQL Server stored procedure
- to display a text box in the same webpage where users can input data
- to display a button in the webpage that takes the inputted data from the text box, runs it through the stored procedure as a parameter, and refreshes the table.

Ideally I'd like this all to happen without the user having to refresh the webpage.

My questions are: is this kind of thing possible? How difficult is it to achieve? And how do I do it? I don't have the time to learn web development in full. I wouldn't need the vast majority of skills I'd learn even if I did learn it in full. I just really need this basic functionality, to produce ultra simple pages when user requests come in.

If anyone knows of any examples of just this kind of thing, that I can copy, they would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: google for the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC tutorial, it will show you the basics.

Comment: Maybe [check this out](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/)?

Comment: Power Apps are good, but they don't let you run a stored procedure, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use MVC, WebForms or even C# for that matter. Using one of those would be killing a ant with a rocket launcher.

Look into node.js and pug, using a RESTFUL API to deliver the information you need. I don't believe you will need more than two hours to provide your users with the interface you told us.

Node has a awesome package called express, it sets up everything for you and uses Pug on the starter template.

You can check out a tutorial right [here](https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb).

Answer (score 1):

Actually it will also take 2 hours doing with Webforms or MVC . I recommend using Entity Framework to make it super simple. 
Webforms may be a bit older technology but will be faster to develop this specific page (assuming you only targeting Desktop users). Otherwise MVC is the way to go.
You can Check the tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started